# Transfer data from one database table to another database table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have requirement to transfer data from old database running on different server to new database which is with different database schema. since I don't need all the tables and may be all columns from a single tables.

I am aware of SSIS, but not really sure it is best way to move forward

I got visual studio 2017 with SSDT

Comment: So what *have* you done so far? This seems more like you're asking for a tool recommendation, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: SSIS is a pretty good option if you know how to work with it. You can also import or export data in SQL Server Management Studio by right-clicking the database and choose Tasks -> Import or Export, if it's a one time thing. If the table schemas differ, you could also import data from the old database into new "staging tables" within your new database and then use a handmade SQL script to insert data into the final table from there. Depends on your requirements, though.

Comment: thanks onkel, that helps

Comment: Hi larnu, yes I am analysing which is better approach, also I have not use SSIS so don't want to spend time where it might not be right solution for me

Comment: If you prefer a UI type approach and the data is on different servers, definitely start with SSIS

Comment: If you don't want to use SSIS then you can setup a linked server from the original server to the new server. You can write SQL to do your conversions and insert the data needed across the link.